# UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

When I used pytorch(without cuda),I run others project,then I meet a following question,but I am actually install library mkl-service and numpy.
error message are fllowing:
D:\software\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
from . import *distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\software\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py", line 22, in 
from . import multiarray
File "D:\software\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in 
from . import overrides
File "D:\software\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in 
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

I also update numpy,I do not what should I do now.Please help me!

Comment: And I am sure I add conda to my enviroment path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.